# Change input locale (keyboard -- left shift+ alt + 1) key sequence PROGRAMMATICALLY

Tags: c++, layout, input, keyboard, locale

On XP, if you go to

```
control panel -> regional and language Options -> Languages Tab -> Details ->
```

If you have more than one keyboard in use, then, click `Key Settings`.  Those are the settings I would like to change.  I would like to set it up so that the DVORAK keyboard is `Left Alt + Shift + 1`.   I can use C++, C# or whatever.  I already know how to load a keyboard:

```
HKL dvorakhkl = LoadKeyboardLayout(TEXT("00010409"), 0);
```

That loads the dvorak keyboard.  This sets it to default:

```
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDEFAULTINPUTLANG, 0, (PVOID)&dvorakhkl, 0);
```

Also, I can change the top part of said dialog box

> "Switch between Input Languages"

```
UINT val = 1;//"1" = ALT+SHIFT, "2" = CTRL+SHIFT, and "3" = none.
System.ParametersInfo(SPI_SETLANGTOGGLE, 0, 0, val);
```

Let me know if you can help.  Thanks!

Aaron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default all programs use the C local (Because we all program in C dialects I suppose)

You can imbue streams with an appropriate local.
Just remember that you must imbue the stream before opening/using it. An attempt to imbue a stream after it has been opened/used will be silently ignored.

This means that for std::cin and std::cout you should probably do it immediately on startup in main() to avoid the potential of them being used.

When creating a locale object if you specify the empty striung it will pick up the name of the local from the environment (ie one of the environment variables).

See:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios_base/imbue/

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear.  I'm talking about changing global user settings like current keyboard layout, as if they were changed in the Control Panel.  Thanks for the info, though!